# Определить путь для выполнения

Tags: java, cmd

Нахожусь в папке `C:\example`. Файл `Example.class` находится в папке `C:\example\bin`. Как выполнить его из папки `C:\example`?

Не получается так:

```
C:\example>java path /bin/Example   
C:\example>java /bin/Example   
C:\example>java -cp /bin/Example
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
java -cp bin Example
```

`-cp bin` укажет, в какой директории искать файл.

Comment: Спасибо большое